# How to properly print a url in jupyter lab?

Tags: python, html, jupyter

This a url for searching the keyword google on google.com:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=google&rlz=1C1CHBD_elGR899GR899&oq=google&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l4j69i65l2j69i60.1647j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
```

If I execute the following cell in jupyter lab,

```
print("https://www.google.com/search?q=google&rlz=1C1CHBD_elGR899GR899&oq=google&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l4j69i65l2j69i60.1647j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8")
```

I get:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=google&amp;rlz=1C1CHBD_elGR899GR899&amp;oq=google&amp;aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l4j69i65l2j69i60.1647j0j7&amp;sourceid=chrome&amp;ie=UTF-8
```

How can I avoid `&` being displayed as `&amp;` ?

Answer (score 1):

I found out this is caused by Jupyter creating a clickable link. If you prefix the string you are trying to print with 'x' for example, it does not happen and the ampersand is not escaped.